Vibrational degree of freedom for monoatomic gases
I read that, when the temperature of a gas becomes high enough, a third type of degree of freedom becomes accessible, viz. the vibrational degree of freedom.
Also (at high temperatures) there is a vibrational kinetic energy and a vibrational potential energy gained by the system, which together constitute the vibrational D.O.F; this adds "+2", to the "degree of freedom at low temperatures", at high temperatures.
The reason my teacher teaches is (at high school level): In the kinetic theory of gases we assume that there is no interaction between the molecules of a perfect/ideal gas. Thus, we can't define a potential energy function. (We can define electrostatic potential energy for the Coulomb force; in case of a perfect gas, no force exists between the molecules, so no P.E function can be defined.)
So it seems that, at high temperatures, the molecules of di/poly-atomic gases start to interact and a P.E function can be defined and therefore potential energy is gained by the system.
When there is a monoatomic gas like He, there is nothing it can interact with because it is monoatomic, so there is no potential energy.
Does this mean, only di/poly atomic gases can have vibrational D.O.F and not mono; and that can we add "+2" to only di/poly atomic gases and not mono?
But a monoatomic gas can have vibrational kinetic energy and by above analysis it cannot have potential energy. Does this mean that we can add "+1" for monoatomic gases, like we do "+2" for di/poly-atomic, at high temperatures.

Take a look at these vibrational modes for $CO_2$, and see if you can find an analogous mode for $He$: https://www.chem.purdue.edu/jmol/vibs/co2.html

@Sidd I can't find even a single monoatomic gas! Does this mean, monoatomic gases have zero vibrational D.O.F, even at high temperatures?

Yes; there is no vibrational motion that is distinct from motion in the x,y,z coordinates.

@Sidd and what about the vibrational potential energy?

The vibrational potential energy is a function of the distance between the atoms in a molecule. For a monoatomic species, there is no such distance, hence no vibrational potential energy.

@Sidd I understand, but then why can't there be an interaction between different, say, He atoms? Intramolecular interactions are not possible for monoatomic gases; why not intermolecular interactions, so we can define a P.E function then???

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@ApoorvaShukla vibrational kinetic energy is between the atoms of gas molecule, visualize two atoms connected by a spring. Since monatomic gases only have a single atom, they can’t have vibrational KE

You are exactly correct that monatomic gases have only translational DOF, and not rotational or vibrational.
Monotonic gases like helium have specific heat capacities of $C_V = \frac 3 2R$ and $C_P = \frac 5 2R$, while diatomic gases like nitrogen have $C_V = \frac 5 2R$ and $C_V = \frac 7 2R$ near room temperature.  This difference is observable in thermal data in systems with the different gases.  It is also observable in the speed of sound in the gases which equals
$\sqrt{ \frac {C_P}{C_V}RT}$
Monatomics like helium cannot store energy in vibration because there is no way for it to vibrate – unlike a diatomic where the two atoms can get closer or farther like balls on a spring.   If you heat up the helium gas enough you will end up exciting electronic energy levels (electrons jumping to higher orbitals) which will add to the heat capacity in a different way.
